# ReactJS - Draw an ER diagram with relations from JSON object?

Tags: json, reactjs, erd

I'm trying to draw an **ER diagram** from a **JSON file** with ReactJS. I have a file where I can see tables and relations between them ("relations" in the object). Like a database, with objects.

How would I create such an ER diagram or Scheme with ReactJS? I didn't manage to use Storm Diagrams as a beginner, I didn't know how it would look.

The JSON object contains tables such as tasks, users, annotations and relations between them in each table for foreign keys. I want some kind of way to show the DB tables and render them from the JSON object.
**Here is my JSON object:**

```
  "tasks": {
    "columns": [
      "id",
      "name",
      "task_type",
      "organization_id",
      "documentation",
      "created_at"
    ],
    "relations": []
  },
  "users": {
    "columns": [
      "id",
      "name",
      "permissions",
      "organization_id",
      "created_at"
    ],
    "relations": []
  },
  "user_tasks": {
    "columns": [
      "id",
      "user_id",
      "task_id",
      "created_at"
    ],
    "relations": [
      [
        "user_id",
        "users",
        "id"
      ],
      [
        "task_id",
        "tasks",
        "id"
      ]
    ]
  },
  "data": {
    "columns": [
      "id",
      "metadata_id",
      "sha256",
      "file_name",
      "audio_data_type_id",
      "created_at"
    ],
    "relations": [
      [
        "metadata_id",
        "data_metadata",
        "id"
      ],
      [
        "audio_data_type_id",
        "audio_data_types",
        "id"
      ]
    ]
  },
  "tasks_data": {
    "columns": [
      "id",
      "task_id",
      "data_id",
      "priority",
      "created_at"
    ],
    "relations": [
      [
        "task_id",
        "tasks",
        "id"
      ],
      [
        "data_id",
        "data",
        "id"
      ]
    ]
  },
  "data_metadata": {
    "columns": [
      "id",
      "name",
      "country",
      "region",
      "primary_language",
      "organization_id",
      "created_at"
    ],
    "relations": []
  },
  "annotation_types": {
    "columns": [
      "id",
      "created_by",
      "objective_name",
      "label_name",
      "organization_id",
      "deleted_at",
      "created_at",
      "value_type"
    ],
    "relations": [
      [
        "created_by",
        "users",
        "id"
      ]
    ]
  },
  "audio_data_types": {
    "columns": [
      "id",
      "bit_width",
      "channels",
      "encoding",
      "sampling_rate"
    ],
    "relations": []
  },
  "audio_annotations": {
    "columns": [
      "id",
      "root_id",
      "child_id",
      "parent_id",
      "annotation_type_id",
      "created_by",
      "task_id",
      "data_id",
      "value",
      "confidence",
      "created_at",
      "deleted_at",
      "speaker",
      "start_time",
      "stop_time"
    ],
    "relations": [
      [
        "task_id",
        "tasks",
        "id"
      ],
      [
        "created_by",
        "users",
        "id"
      ],
      [
        "data_id",
        "data",
        "id"
      ],
      [
        "annotation_type_id",
        "annotation_types",
        "id"
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```